# Retrieve data with Where Clause when data on different Row

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm facing yet another issue with the following design of database.

Let's say it's a list of Chat, and another table, user that belong to that chat.

ChatListDB

1. ID
2. last_message

ChatListUsersDB

1. ID
2. ChatListDB_ID
3. UserToken

I would like to check if that Chat exist between these two users "Token1" and "Token2"

I cant simply do a query and put both token in Where Clause because they are on different row obviously.

**What I want to achieve**

How do i check if lets say ChatListDB's ID is 1234, How do i check if both token(Token1 & Token2) is already in ChatlistUserDB with the SAME ChatlistDB ID

Comment: if you want to see if a number exists more then 2 times you can always use count  but for me its kind of vague what you want to achief, can you maybe post some more info?

Comment: As in like,  i want to check if the chat does exist between the two users.

Comment: I cant simply do a Where->(Token = "Token1") and Where->(Token = "Token2")

Comment: but you can use HAVING, if you want to filter AFTER a query has runned, i hope that might help

Comment: so i hope this is what you mean....

SELECT * FROM ChatListUsersDB WHERE (UserToken = nr1 OR userToken = nr2) AND ChatListDB_ID = 1234

this should return 2 rows if your tokens are there, right?

Comment: @lauw yaeh soemthing like that! but without the AND because i dont have the ChatListDB_ID yet! Which if it exist between two users, i dont want to make another

Comment: @lauw and that would lead to multiple returned row which requires more filtering

Comment: you may count the row ...  SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM ChatListUsersDB WHERE UserToken = 'nr1' OR UserToken = 'nr2' . Here if cnt is 2, both are exists...

Comment: Use left or right join with count

Comment: @VijaySankhat isnt that for joining like two different tables?

Comment: @CodeGuru Yes correct

Answer (score 1):

since i dont exactly know what your ideal return result should be you can also have a simple true, false answer with this query:

```
SELECT if((SELECT count(*) FROM ChatListUsersDB WHERE (UserToken = nr1 OR userToken = nr2)) = 2, 'true', 'false') AS answer
```